# serdev not sending when i enable flow control

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I created a serdev device driver and want to enable the CTS/RTS pins for my hardware flow control. When the flow control is disabled like this: `serdev_device_set_flow_control(serdev, false);` it is sending. But as soon as I enable it, it will not send anymore.
So i looked at the implementation:

```
void serdev_device_set_flow_control(struct serdev_device *serdev, bool enable)
{
    struct serdev_controller *ctrl = serdev->ctrl;

    if (!ctrl || !ctrl->ops->set_flow_control)
        return;

    ctrl->ops->set_flow_control(ctrl, enable);
}
```

Before I call it I verified my controller is there and my property `set_flow_control` is `true`. So that looks fine. So it should be set. But it is not sending anymore.

Thanks for the feedback here is my inizialisation:

```
    struct serdev_controller *ctrl = serdev->ctrl;
    struct stmuart *stm;
    int speed = 3000000u;
    int ret;

    pr_info("Insert Network driver\n");
    
    stm = devm_kzalloc(&serdev->dev, sizeof(*stm), GFP_KERNEL);
    
    stm->serdev = serdev;

    INIT_WORK(&stm->tx_work, stmuart_transmit);

    serdev_device_set_drvdata(serdev, stm);
    serdev_device_set_client_ops(serdev, &stm_serdev_ops);

    ret = serdev_device_open(serdev);
    if (ret) {
        dev_err(&serdev->dev, "Unable to open device\n");
        goto free;
    }
    
    speed = serdev_device_set_baudrate(serdev, speed);
    dev_info(&serdev->dev, "Using baudrate: %u\n", speed);

    serdev_device_set_flow_control(serdev, true);
    dev_info(&serdev->dev, "set_flow_control: %s\n", ctrl->ops->set_flow_control ? "true" : "false");
    
    return 0;
    
free:
    return ret;
```

I checked it with the oszi and it is not not sending and the CTS and RTS pins are not changing.

Here is my Device tree configuration.

```
usart3: serial@4000f000 {
            compatible = "st,stm32h7-uart";
            reg = <0x4000f000 0x400>;
            interrupts-extended = <&exti 28 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
            clocks = <&rcc USART3_K>;
            wakeup-source;
            power-domains = <&pd_core>;
            dmas = <&dmamux1 45 0x400 0x15>,
                   <&dmamux1 46 0x400 0x11>;
            dma-names = "rx", "tx";
            status = "ok";
            
            ethernet {
                compatible = "st,stm32_usart_net";
                local-mac-address = [ A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 ];
                current-speed = <38400>;
                };
        };
```

My other device tree file

```
&usart3 {
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep", "idle";
    pinctrl-0 = <&usart3_pins_c>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&usart3_sleep_pins_c>;
    pinctrl-2 = <&usart3_idle_pins_c>;
    uart-has-rtscts;
    status = "ok";
};
```

I disabled the hardwareflow control and trieed to set my RTS manually with `serdev_device_set_tiocm(serdev, 0, TIOCM_RTS);`but its not changing.

Comment: There is more to the problem then your code example currently shows.  How is this function called?  How are the members of `struct serdev_device *serdev` initialized before being passed as an argument.  The post needs to be updated with enough information (including answers to these questions.) to troubleshoot and offer suggestions.  If possible, provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is this: `ctrl->ops->set_flow_control(ctrl, enable);` ???  `C` cannot have members functions.   I am pretty sure that the code you have posted does not compile.  Along with [mcve], please include `struct` definitions for `struct serdev_device` and `struct serdev_controller`

Comment: I showed how i inizialize my stuff. the code i showed first is the source code from linux. my code is compinling.

Comment: If this is `C` code, then the line `ctrl->ops->set_flow_control(ctrl, enable);`, (which appears to be in some form of a function member of a struct) cannot exist.  i.e. A `C` compiler will cough and spit it out with an error message.  And thank you for adding more information, but you have yet to respond with a minimal, compilable example that includes what you believe to be the offending area(s) in the code.  Unless you can do that I do not think the question as is, is answerable.

Comment: I only posted the code snipped because i checkted my propertys. Heres the link to the original code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/serdev/core.c#L352. But i am only lusing it in my code.

Comment: @ryyker It's likely just some function pointer. Which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Now what happens when you single step through `serdev_device_set_flow_control` in your debugger? Does it enter `set_flow_control`? And what goes on at the CTS/RTS pins when you check them with your oscilloscope?

Comment: Yes it come there this is why i logged it with dev_info. So if is serdev_device_set_flow_control(serdev, fase);
it is sending and my CTS/RTS pins do nothing. So i changed it to:
serdev_device_set_flow_control(serdev, true);
But now my CTS/RTS pin is not toggeling and it is not sending anymore.

Comment: Since it stopped sending when you enabled hardware flow control, that suggests the hardware flow control functionality is working OK. It will only transmit when the CTS input signal is asserted.

Comment: You have mentioned that the CTS/RTS pins are not changing, but you have not mentioned the initial state of these signals, which would seem to be relevant here (especially CTS).

Comment: My RTS is Low and my CTS is high.

Comment: And on the other side?

Comment: RX and TX are also high.

Comment: I alo noticed when i trie to enable the RTS pin with the serdev_device_set_rts methode it is always low.

Comment: Also if i try to enable or disable the RTS/CTS pin like that it is not changing. serdev_device_set_tiocm(serdev, TIOCM_CTS, 0);

Comment: i tried to enable/disable flow contro but i still cant change the rts pin with serdev_device_set_rts.

Comment: I think you will need to investigate what is happening in the uart driver code for the serial port. Do you know which uart driver the serial port is using? Or if you are using device trees, what is the serial port node's "compatible" string?

Comment: I added the device tree settings now. So i found out if i conect the CTS to the RTS port i am able to send and recive. I can set the RTS signal high or low when i enable the serdev_device_set_flow_control. But the signal is not changin to high or low. Also when i change the RTS signal with serdev_device_set_rts it is not changing.

Comment: Because later on i wanted to make it a RS458 comunication. So i just started with some tests.

Comment: Is the pinctrl stuff for USART3_RTS and USART3_CTS set up OK in the device tree? Also, the "stm32-usart" driver ("drivers/tty/serial/stm32-usart.c") will only enable the USART's automatic hardware flow control feature if the `uart-has-rtscts;` boolean property is present in the serial port's device tree node. (The deprecated `st,hw-flow-ctrl;` boolean property does the same thing.

Comment: Is is enabled. in the other file i added. But i still wonder why cant i change the RTS and CTS pin manually.

Comment: The USART doesn't seem to support setting RTS manually. Setting or clearing RTS through the driver modifies the automatic RTS flow control enable (RTSE) bit in the USART's CR3 register. I don't know what state the RTS pin would be when RTSE=0.

Comment: It does when i use this usart as a character device i am able to set hardware flow control or to use it as rs458.

Comment: I read that a serdev cant manualy control CTS and RTS pins. At the moment. Is that true?

Comment: RTS can be controlled by `serdev_device_set_tiocm(serdev, TIOCM_RTS, 0);` (to set RTS), or `serdev_device_set_tiocm(serdev, 0, TIOCM_RTS);` (to clear RTS) as long as the lower level drivers and hardware support it. For the "stm32-usart" driver, the auto-RTS feature (RTSE in the CR3 register) is enabled if and only if the TIOCM_RTS mctrl bit and the CRTSCTS termios flag are set. CTS cannot be controlled because it is an input.

Comment: Thanks for the Information. But like i wrote this is not changing my pin. Could it bee that my device tree is not working.